# State space model with third or more order trend

Tags: bayesian, state-space-models

In state space model, a system model with first order trend is represented as

$$
x_{t} = x_{t-1} + e_{t},
$$

where $x_{t}$ is system model, $e_{t}$ is system noise.

Also, a system model with second order trend is represented as

$$
x_{t} = 2x_{t-1} - x_{t-2} + e_{t}.
$$

Now, I don't know how a system model with third or more order trend can be represented.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, you are looking for ARIMA models, not state-space models. In backshift operator notation:
\begin{equation}
B^n x_t = x_{t-n}
\end{equation}
For example:
\begin{equation}
(1-B)^2x_t = e_t \Leftrightarrow x_t=2x_{t-1} - x_{t-2} + e_t
\end{equation}
Then the model with n-th order trend will be:
\begin{equation}
(1-B)^nx_t = e_t
\end{equation}